# DNAT packet after decryption of ipsec

Tags: iptables, linux-networking

how to DNAT packet decrypted by ipsec.
encrypted packet is:
sourceIP: 192.168.4.6 destIP 10.10.0.100:

If i simply :

```
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  d 10.10.0.100 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.5
```

it doesnt work - it seems that prerouting is doing nat on encrypted traffic - how to force it to work after decryption ?

Answer (score 1):

Tell your rule only to match traffic that's been through the ipsec decrypt-and-verify step:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.10.0.100 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir in -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.5
```

Comment: hmm - i have an error: Cannot use -X with A

Comment: What line did you enter?  I see no `-X` above!

Comment: i have entered:  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.88.15.159 --pol ipsec --dir in -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.5 and got an error: iptables v1.4.14: Cannot use -X with -A

Comment: Weird, me too.  Never seen that before.  Try the above, which doesn't throw the same error.

Comment: i have changet it to  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.88.15.159 --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.5 and no error but i am not sure if it works correctly

Comment: Well, test it, then!

Comment: @Kriss What's the output of `type -a iptables` ? It seems you got the iptables binary call overriden with a weird alias.

Comment: Xavier: what makes you think that?